# Put a list of Hibernate objects into a JSON object

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate

I want to add a list of Hibernate objects into a JSON object but I get `StackOverflowError`.

I also tried `@JsonBackReference("mamRequestHeaders.mamRequestLinesSet")` in `MAMRequestLine.java` and  `@JsonManagedReference("mamRequestHeaders.mamRequestLinesSet")` in `MAMRequestHeader.java` but the problem was not resolved.

> java.lang.StackOverflowError    at
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.(InvocationTargetException.java:72)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor494.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:988)  at
>   org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:272)   at
>   org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1587)    at
>   org.json.JSONArray.(JSONArray.java:158)     at
>   org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1569)    at
>   org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:990)  at
>   org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:272)   at
>   org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1587)    at
>   org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:990)

**`MAMRequestHeaders` class**

```
@Entity(name="MAMRequestHeaders")
@Table(name = "MAM_REQUEST_HEADERS", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"REQUEST_TYPE", "NUM_REQUEST_MREQH"}))
public class MAMRequestHeaders  implements Serializable {

    private long id ;
    private Set<MAMRequestLines> mamRequestLinesSet;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "MAM_REQUEST_HEADERS_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "MAM_REQUEST_HEADERS_SEQ", sequenceName = "MAM_REQUEST_HEADERS_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "REQUEST_HEADER_ID")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mamRequestHeaders", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    public Set<MAMRequestLines> getMamRequestLinesSet() {
        return mamRequestLinesSet;
    }

    public void setMamRequestLinesSet(Set<MAMRequestLines> mamRequestLinesSet) {
        this.mamRequestLinesSet = mamRequestLinesSet;
    }

}
```

**`MAMRequestLines` class**

```
@Entity(name = "MAMRequestLines")
@Table(name = "MAM_REQUEST_LINES", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"REQUEST_HEADER_ID", "NUM_LINE_MREQL"}))
public class MAMRequestLines implements Serializable {

    private Long id;
    @JsonIgnore
    private MAMRequestHeaders mamRequestHeaders;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "MAM_REQUEST_Line_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "MAM_REQUEST_Line_SEQ", sequenceName = "MAM_REQUEST_Line_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "REQUEST_LINE_ID")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "REQUEST_HEADER_ID", nullable = false)
    public MAMRequestHeaders getMamRequestHeaders() {
        return mamRequestHeaders;
    }

    public void setMamRequestHeaders(MAMRequestHeaders mamRequestHeaders) {
        this.mamRequestHeaders = mamRequestHeaders;
    }

}
```

**Creating result**

```
List<MAMRequestHeaders> mamRequestHeadersList =  manager.createQuery(queryStr, MAMRequestHeaders.class)
JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
result.put("resultList", mamRequestHeadersList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `@JsonManagedReference` on your `@OneToMany` collection, and `@JsonBackReference` on your `@ManyToOne` field. Please see the updated example below.

**`MAMRequestHeaders` class**

```
@Entity(name="MAMRequestHeaders")
@Table(name = "MAM_REQUEST_HEADERS", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"REQUEST_TYPE", "NUM_REQUEST_MREQH"}))
public class MAMRequestHeaders  implements Serializable {

    private long id;

    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<MAMRequestLines> mamRequestLinesSet;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "MAM_REQUEST_HEADERS_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "MAM_REQUEST_HEADERS_SEQ", sequenceName = "MAM_REQUEST_HEADERS_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "REQUEST_HEADER_ID")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mamRequestHeaders", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    public Set<MAMRequestLines> getMamRequestLinesSet() {
        return mamRequestLinesSet;
    }

    public void setMamRequestLinesSet(Set<MAMRequestLines> mamRequestLinesSet) {
        this.mamRequestLinesSet = mamRequestLinesSet;
    }

}
```

**`MAMRequestLines` class**

```
@Entity(name = "MAMRequestLines")
@Table(name = "MAM_REQUEST_LINES", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"REQUEST_HEADER_ID", "NUM_LINE_MREQL"}))
public class MAMRequestLines implements Serializable {

    private Long id;

    @JsonManagedReference
    private MAMRequestHeaders mamRequestHeaders;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "MAM_REQUEST_Line_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "MAM_REQUEST_Line_SEQ", sequenceName = "MAM_REQUEST_Line_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "REQUEST_LINE_ID")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "REQUEST_HEADER_ID", nullable = false)
    public MAMRequestHeaders getMamRequestHeaders() {
        return mamRequestHeaders;
    }

    public void setMamRequestHeaders(MAMRequestHeaders mamRequestHeaders) {
        this.mamRequestHeaders = mamRequestHeaders;
    }

}
```

But actually configuring the JSON annotations depends on your desired output. For example you could also put `@JsonIgnore` on the `getMamRequestHeaders()` in your `MAMRequestLines` class.